# Remove the flaring edge of Moon/Earth in SkyX

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Using [this pull request to gazebo_models](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_models/pull-request/124/add-apollo15_landing_site/diff#comment-5485688) and the suggestions there, we're now holding a <s>moonlight</s> earthlight party using Gazebo, by simply replacing `SkyX_Moon.png` with an earth image included in [this PR](https://github.com/tork-a/hakuto/pull/39).

[image: tetris simulation with earth from the lunar surface]

I think the flaring rim surrounding the earth was suitable for the moon seen from the earth, but not the other way round. Where should I edit SkyX to remove it? Thank you.

---

UPDATE: Thanks to @iche033's answer, we now enjoy even more serene moment.

[image: earth w/o fragment]

```
$ diff /usr/share/gazebo-2.2/media/skyx/SkyX_Moon.fragment.org /usr/share/gazebo-2.2/media/skyx/SkyX_Moon.fragment
60c60
<   haloIntensity = pow(haloIntensity, uMoonPhase.z);
---
>   haloIntensity = pow(0.0, uMoonPhase.z);
```

Catch for me was that this `.fragment` file seems to not work right with some comment-out formats; I was trying to use `#` and it just didn't show the earth at all.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8401/remove-the-flaring-edge-of-moon/earth-in-skyx/) by [IsaacS](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/15/isaacs/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 118 on 2015-04-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

try setting the `haloIntensity` to 0.0 in [SkyX_Moon.fragment](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/d6c6e3d6048edca82d6fce6aaff65c59b4b98bcc/media/skyx/SkyX_Moon.fragment#cl-60)

---

Originally posted by [iche033](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/58/iche033/) with karma: 1018 on 2015-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1